# What does "Insert into Table (column_1) VALUES ('Active transaction')" in results from sp_WhoIsActive mean

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

What does

```
Insert into dbo.B1600106C07E4DA19D9C7F1A89B3CDD1 
(column_1) 
VALUES ('Active transaction')
```

in the `sql_text` column from sp_WhoIsActive mean?

The login is "sa", we don't have a table by that name and no one uses that login. I don't understand where this is coming from or know how to find out. Incidentally, this can sometimes cause blocking issues and I would like to understand where this is coming from.

We're using SQL server 2019 and DB compatibility is 2016.

Comment: Do you guys use Acronis backup software?

Comment: I'm not sure if we use Acronis. We might. Could that cause this?

Comment: If the column name is actually `column_1` then I doubt that this is anything from the product itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if we use Acronis. We might. Could that cause this?

That table name appears to be a very specifically generated sequence of characters. The only other site that comes up on a Google search on it is a [question on the Acronis backups forum](https://forum.acronis.com/forum/acronis-backup-125/125-registration-failed-urgent).

Someone posted their log file of their Acronis backup software and it mentions that table name in addition to this same query syntax / nomenclature: `(column_1) VALUES ('Active transaction')`. I doubt that's a coincidence.

You should talk to the rest of your team and find out if you're using Acronis backups (which I'd bet my money on you are).

Comment: We are using Acronis. Thank you